# how to concatenate the content of a file with a increment of last number of the column

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, echo

i have a file with some content and need to repeat nth time and addition to increment of last column number.

```
Input content of a file:
TCTA    7   ccta    TCTA    1
TCTA    8   ccta    TCTA    1
TCTA    9   ccta    TCTA    1
TCTA    10  ccta    TCTA    1
TCTA    11  ccta    TCTA    1
TCTA    12  ccta    TCTA    1
TCTA    13  ccta    TCTA    1
TCTA    14  ccta    TCTA    1
TCTA    15  ccta    TCTA    1
TCTA    16  ccta    TCTA    1
TCTA    17  ccta    TCTA    1

Expected output:
TCTA    7   ccta    TCTA    1
TCTA    8   ccta    TCTA    1
TCTA    9   ccta    TCTA    1
TCTA    10  ccta    TCTA    1
TCTA    11  ccta    TCTA    1
TCTA    12  ccta    TCTA    1
TCTA    13  ccta    TCTA    1
TCTA    14  ccta    TCTA    1
TCTA    15  ccta    TCTA    1
TCTA    16  ccta    TCTA    1
TCTA    17  ccta    TCTA    1
TCTA    7   ccta    TCTA    2
TCTA    8   ccta    TCTA    2
TCTA    9   ccta    TCTA    2
TCTA    10  ccta    TCTA    2
TCTA    11  ccta    TCTA    2
TCTA    12  ccta    TCTA    2
TCTA    13  ccta    TCTA    2
TCTA    14  ccta    TCTA    2
TCTA    15  ccta    TCTA    2
TCTA    16  ccta    TCTA    2
TCTA    17  ccta    TCTA    2
TCTA    7   ccta    TCTA    3
TCTA    8   ccta    TCTA    3
TCTA    9   ccta    TCTA    3
TCTA    10  ccta    TCTA    3
TCTA    11  ccta    TCTA    3
TCTA    12  ccta    TCTA    3
TCTA    13  ccta    TCTA    3
TCTA    14  ccta    TCTA    3
TCTA    15  ccta    TCTA    3
TCTA    16  ccta    TCTA    3
TCTA    17  ccta    TCTA    3
TCTA    7   ccta    TCTA    n
TCTA    8   ccta    TCTA    n
TCTA    9   ccta    TCTA    n
TCTA    10  ccta    TCTA    n
TCTA    11  ccta    TCTA    n
TCTA    12  ccta    TCTA    n
TCTA    13  ccta    TCTA    n
TCTA    14  ccta    TCTA    n
TCTA    15  ccta    TCTA    n
TCTA    16  ccta    TCTA    n
TCTA    17  ccta    TCTA    n
```

I tried following but unable to make last column increment by nth time.

```
for i in {1..5};do 
   cat file.txt >> out.txt
done
```

I need the last column to increased by nth time.

Comment: Is the input file guaranteed to have the same number in the last column?

Is that number guaranteed to be one?

If the number differs, should lines be repeated only until the final number has been incremented to the specified maximum value (i.e., should some lines appear in the output more times than others)?

Comment: In each iteration, you have to replace the last number in the line by the current sequence number. Therefore, you can't use cat. Instead you must - inside each iteration of `i`- write an explicit loop over the lines of the input file and for each line adjust the last field of the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a gnu-awk solution:

```sh
awk -v n=3 '
{
   rec = rec $0 RS
}
1
END {
   for (i=2; i<=n; ++i)
      printf "%s", gensub(/[0-9]+(\n|$)/, i "\\1", "g", rec)
}' file

TCTA    7   ccta    TCTA    1
TCTA    8   ccta    TCTA    1
TCTA    9   ccta    TCTA    1
TCTA    10  ccta    TCTA    1
TCTA    11  ccta    TCTA    1
TCTA    12  ccta    TCTA    1
TCTA    13  ccta    TCTA    1
TCTA    14  ccta    TCTA    1
TCTA    15  ccta    TCTA    1
TCTA    16  ccta    TCTA    1
TCTA    17  ccta    TCTA    1
TCTA    7   ccta    TCTA    2
TCTA    8   ccta    TCTA    2
TCTA    9   ccta    TCTA    2
TCTA    10  ccta    TCTA    2
TCTA    11  ccta    TCTA    2
TCTA    12  ccta    TCTA    2
TCTA    13  ccta    TCTA    2
TCTA    14  ccta    TCTA    2
TCTA    15  ccta    TCTA    2
TCTA    16  ccta    TCTA    2
TCTA    17  ccta    TCTA    2
TCTA    7   ccta    TCTA    3
TCTA    8   ccta    TCTA    3
TCTA    9   ccta    TCTA    3
TCTA    10  ccta    TCTA    3
TCTA    11  ccta    TCTA    3
TCTA    12  ccta    TCTA    3
TCTA    13  ccta    TCTA    3
TCTA    14  ccta    TCTA    3
TCTA    15  ccta    TCTA    3
TCTA    16  ccta    TCTA    3
TCTA    17  ccta    TCTA    3
```

Comment: Hi Anubhav

Thanks its working though (i need to install; "brew install gawk" and used gawk instead awk only). Moreover, i never used gensub function, can you please explain all, how your commands explain the situation ? 
Thanks

Comment: `gensub` is using regex `[0-9]+(\n|$)` for searching in string `rec`. Which is basically last number in each line and replacing that with `i` which is iterating from `2` to `n`. `(\n|$)` is a capture group to capture each line break or end of line and in replacement we just put it back after `i` using back-reference `\\1`. `"g"` is for global replacement.

Comment: Hey Anubhav

Thanks, can you help me if i want to extend for second last column as well as for last column as input changed?


`TCTA 3 TCTG 1 TCTA 1`


`TCTA 4 TCTG 1 TCTA 1`

Comment: @SandeepKumar It is very difficult to understand requirement from comment section. It will be much better if you create a new question and you'll get best of the help.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU parallel and sed):

```
parallel -kq sed -E 's/\S+$/$((&+{}))/;s/.*/echo "&"/e' file ::: {0..2}
```

If you want to replace the last field by an increment, use:

```
parallel -kq sed -E 's/\S+$/{}/' file ::: {1..3}
```