# Concatenate the content of a file with a increment of columns has 1 only

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

In the line of previous post ([how to concatenate the content of a file with a increment of last number of the column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69729001/15410245)), i need help with a little different issue.

Now **i like to have increment (1 to 5th times) of every columns** (can be 2nd, 3rd ....nth which certainly will start and end with "1" only) **except the first column** (which may start from 1 but end with any number).

input file:

```
TCTA    3   TCTG    1   TCTA    1
TCTA    4   TCTG    1   TCTA    1
TCTA    5   TCTG    1   TCTA    1
TCTA    6   TCTG    1   TCTA    1
TCTA    7   TCTG    1   TCTA    1
TCTA    8   TCTG    1   TCTA    1
TCTA    9   TCTG    1   TCTA    1
TCTA    10  TCTG    1   TCTA    1
TCTA    11  TCTG    1   TCTA    1
TCTA    12  TCTG    1   TCTA    1
TCTA    13  TCTG    1   TCTA    1
TCTA    14  TCTG    1   TCTA    1
TCTA    15  TCTG    1   TCTA    1
```

output required:

```
TCTA    3   TCTG    1   TCTA    1
TCTA    4   TCTG    1   TCTA    1
TCTA    5   TCTG    1   TCTA    1
TCTA    6   TCTG    1   TCTA    1
TCTA    7   TCTG    1   TCTA    1
TCTA    8   TCTG    1   TCTA    1
TCTA    9   TCTG    1   TCTA    1
TCTA    10  TCTG    1   TCTA    1
TCTA    11  TCTG    1   TCTA    1
TCTA    12  TCTG    1   TCTA    1
TCTA    13  TCTG    1   TCTA    1
TCTA    14  TCTG    1   TCTA    1
TCTA    15  TCTG    1   TCTA    1
TCTA    3   TCTG    2   TCTA    2
TCTA    4   TCTG    2   TCTA    2
TCTA    5   TCTG    2   TCTA    2
TCTA    6   TCTG    2   TCTA    2
TCTA    7   TCTG    2   TCTA    2
TCTA    8   TCTG    2   TCTA    2
TCTA    9   TCTG    2   TCTA    2
TCTA    10  TCTG    2   TCTA    2
TCTA    11  TCTG    2   TCTA    2
TCTA    12  TCTG    2   TCTA    2
TCTA    13  TCTG    2   TCTA    2
TCTA    14  TCTG    2   TCTA    2
TCTA    15  TCTG    2   TCTA    2
TCTA    3   TCTG    3   TCTA    3
TCTA    4   TCTG    3   TCTA    3
TCTA    5   TCTG    3   TCTA    3
TCTA    6   TCTG    3   TCTA    3
TCTA    7   TCTG    3   TCTA    3
TCTA    8   TCTG    3   TCTA    3
TCTA    9   TCTG    3   TCTA    3
TCTA    10  TCTG    3   TCTA    3
TCTA    11  TCTG    3   TCTA    3
TCTA    12  TCTG    3   TCTA    3
TCTA    13  TCTG    3   TCTA    3
TCTA    14  TCTG    3   TCTA    3
TCTA    15  TCTG    3   TCTA    3
TCTA    3   TCTG    4   TCTA    4
TCTA    4   TCTG    4   TCTA    4
TCTA    5   TCTG    4   TCTA    4
TCTA    6   TCTG    4   TCTA    4
TCTA    7   TCTG    4   TCTA    4
TCTA    8   TCTG    4   TCTA    4
TCTA    9   TCTG    4   TCTA    4
TCTA    10  TCTG    4   TCTA    4
TCTA    11  TCTG    4   TCTA    4
TCTA    12  TCTG    4   TCTA    4
TCTA    13  TCTG    4   TCTA    4
TCTA    14  TCTG    4   TCTA    4
TCTA    15  TCTG    4   TCTA    4
TCTA    3   TCTG    5   TCTA    5
TCTA    4   TCTG    5   TCTA    5
TCTA    5   TCTG    5   TCTA    5
TCTA    6   TCTG    5   TCTA    5
TCTA    7   TCTG    5   TCTA    5
TCTA    8   TCTG    5   TCTA    5
TCTA    9   TCTG    5   TCTA    5
TCTA    10  TCTG    5   TCTA    5
TCTA    11  TCTG    5   TCTA    5
TCTA    12  TCTG    5   TCTA    5
TCTA    13  TCTG    5   TCTA    5
TCTA    14  TCTG    5   TCTA    5
TCTA    15  TCTG    5   TCTA    5
```

I tried to incorporate the code from previous post but not success so far..

```
awk -v n=3 '
{
   rec = rec $0 RS
}
1
END {
   for (i=2; i<=n; ++i)
      printf "%s", gensub(/[0-9]+(\n|$)/, i "\\1", "g", rec)
}' file
```

Issue here is that it takes only last column, however i need any columns but first.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Is it always columns 4 and 6?

Comment: In this case yes..but may increase the column like 8 and 10....you may say even numbers start from (4,6,8,10....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

- first numeric column does not include the single digit `1`
- for all other columns to be incremented the source/input column's value is `1` (ie, we're only going to increment columns that contain a single `1`)
- net result: replace all occurrences of the single digit `1` with incremented values
- the number of columns is not known beforehand
- the number of columns could vary from row to row

Modifying OP's current `awk` code to replace all standalone `1's` with an incremented value:

```
awk -v n=5 '
{
   rec = rec $0 RS
}
1
END {
   for (i=2; i<=n; ++i) {
       x=gensub(/([^[:digit:]])1([^[:digit:]])/, "\\1" i "\\2", "g", rec)
       printf "%s", gensub(/([^[:digit:]])1([^[:digit:]])/, "\\1" i "\\2", "g", x)
   }
}' file
```

Where:

- `([^[:digit:]])1([^[:digit:]])` matches a non-digit character (capture group #1) + a single `1` + a non-digit character (capture group #2)
- `"\\1" i "\\2"` - replacement is capture group #1 + the current increment value (`i=2..5` in this instance) + capture group #2
- we perform 2x `gensub()` calls to address issue where there are consecutive numeric columns containing a single `1` (**NOTE:** there may be a way to do this with a single function call but I'm drawing a blank at the moment ... open to suggestions from the `awkers` in the community)

Using a modified input file to demonstrate the consecutive numeric column issue:

```
$ cat file
TCTA    3   TCTG    1   TCTA    1
TCTA    4   TCTG    1   TCTA    1
TCTA    5   TCTG    1   TCTA    1
TCTA    6   TCTG    1   TCTA    1
TCTA    7   TCTG    1   TCTA    1
TCTA    8   TCTG    1   TCTA    1
TCTA    9   TCTG    1   TCTA    1
TCTA    10  TCTG    1   TCTA    1
TCTA    11  TCTG    1   TCTA    1
TCTA    12  TCTG    1   TCTA    1
TCTA    13  TCTG    1   TCTA    1
TCTA    14  TCTG    1   TCTA    1 1 1
TCTA    15  TCTG    1   TCTA    1 1 1 1
```

This generates:

```
TCTA    3   TCTG    1   TCTA    1
TCTA    4   TCTG    1   TCTA    1
TCTA    5   TCTG    1   TCTA    1
TCTA    6   TCTG    1   TCTA    1
TCTA    7   TCTG    1   TCTA    1
TCTA    8   TCTG    1   TCTA    1
TCTA    9   TCTG    1   TCTA    1
TCTA    10  TCTG    1   TCTA    1
TCTA    11  TCTG    1   TCTA    1
TCTA    12  TCTG    1   TCTA    1
TCTA    13  TCTG    1   TCTA    1
TCTA    14  TCTG    1   TCTA    1 1 1
TCTA    15  TCTG    1   TCTA    1 1 1 1
TCTA    3   TCTG    2   TCTA    2
TCTA    4   TCTG    2   TCTA    2
TCTA    5   TCTG    2   TCTA    2
TCTA    6   TCTG    2   TCTA    2
TCTA    7   TCTG    2   TCTA    2
TCTA    8   TCTG    2   TCTA    2
TCTA    9   TCTG    2   TCTA    2
TCTA    10  TCTG    2   TCTA    2
TCTA    11  TCTG    2   TCTA    2
TCTA    12  TCTG    2   TCTA    2
TCTA    13  TCTG    2   TCTA    2
TCTA    14  TCTG    2   TCTA    2 2 2
TCTA    15  TCTG    2   TCTA    2 2 2 2
TCTA    3   TCTG    3   TCTA    3
TCTA    4   TCTG    3   TCTA    3
TCTA    5   TCTG    3   TCTA    3
TCTA    6   TCTG    3   TCTA    3
TCTA    7   TCTG    3   TCTA    3
TCTA    8   TCTG    3   TCTA    3
TCTA    9   TCTG    3   TCTA    3
TCTA    10  TCTG    3   TCTA    3
TCTA    11  TCTG    3   TCTA    3
TCTA    12  TCTG    3   TCTA    3
TCTA    13  TCTG    3   TCTA    3
TCTA    14  TCTG    3   TCTA    3 3 3
TCTA    15  TCTG    3   TCTA    3 3 3 3
TCTA    3   TCTG    4   TCTA    4
TCTA    4   TCTG    4   TCTA    4
TCTA    5   TCTG    4   TCTA    4
TCTA    6   TCTG    4   TCTA    4
TCTA    7   TCTG    4   TCTA    4
TCTA    8   TCTG    4   TCTA    4
TCTA    9   TCTG    4   TCTA    4
TCTA    10  TCTG    4   TCTA    4
TCTA    11  TCTG    4   TCTA    4
TCTA    12  TCTG    4   TCTA    4
TCTA    13  TCTG    4   TCTA    4
TCTA    14  TCTG    4   TCTA    4 4 4
TCTA    15  TCTG    4   TCTA    4 4 4 4
TCTA    3   TCTG    5   TCTA    5
TCTA    4   TCTG    5   TCTA    5
TCTA    5   TCTG    5   TCTA    5
TCTA    6   TCTG    5   TCTA    5
TCTA    7   TCTG    5   TCTA    5
TCTA    8   TCTG    5   TCTA    5
TCTA    9   TCTG    5   TCTA    5
TCTA    10  TCTG    5   TCTA    5
TCTA    11  TCTG    5   TCTA    5
TCTA    12  TCTG    5   TCTA    5
TCTA    13  TCTG    5   TCTA    5
TCTA    14  TCTG    5   TCTA    5 5 5
TCTA    15  TCTG    5   TCTA    5 5 5 5
```

Comment: Hi Markp


Thank thats works but even assigning only n = 5 and then use only "n" instead n+1 loop works as well. 
correct me if i am wrong. I am not sure why you have n+1 in the loop, please explain?

Comment: you're right, should be `n` and not `n+1`; I mistook `n` to mean the number of **times**  to increment (ie, `n=3` => increment to 2, 3 and 4) instaed of `n` meaning the last incremental value; I've updated the answer to use `n=5`

Answer (score 1):

It might be that the output is not that great looking, but the easiest would be something like this:

```
awk -v n=5 '{ for(i=1;i<=n;++i) a[i,NR]=sprintf("%-8s%-4d%-8s%-4d%-8s%-4d",$1,$2,$3,i,$5,i) }
     END { for(i=1;i<=n;++i) for(j=1;j<=NR;++j) print a[i,j] }' file
```